Biholomorphism between two complex manifolds
Let $\mathbb C^4$ be the complex vector space equipped with the symmetric bilinear form  of signature $(2,2)$ $$b(z,w) =  z_1w_1 + z_2 w_2- z_3 w_3- z_4 w_4.$$ The set $$X_{\mathbb C} = \{z \in \mathbb C^4 \mid b(z,z) = -1\}$$ is a complex manifold.
Consider the complex sphere  $$\mathbb S_{\mathbb C}^3 = \{z \in \mathbb C^4 \mid z_1^2 +z_2^2 +z_3^2+z_4^2 = 1\}.$$
Is $X_{\mathbb C}$ biholomorphic to $\mathbb S_{\mathbb C}^3$ ?
I think  these two are biholomorphic. But I cannot produce the biholomorphism. Can anyone  please help?

Are there some complex conjugates missing in your bilinear form? Respectively, how do you get that $b(z,z)=1$ implies that $z$ lies on the sphere?

For example $z=(i, 1, 1, 0)$ satisfies $b(z,z)=1$, but is not on the sphere if I am not mistaken.

@SeverinSchraven Sorry, my fault I have misunderstood the question. I have edited the original question.

Rephrasing slightly, the question is whether there exists a holomorphic change of coordinates on $\mathbb{C}^4$, say $\varphi:\mathbb{C}^4\to\mathbb{C}^4$, such that $\varphi^*f=\pm g$, where $f(w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4)=-1+\sum_{i=1}^4w_i^2$ and $g(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=1+z_1^2+z_2^2-z_3^2-z_4^2$. Note that the sign does not matter because we care only about the zero locus. Consider the mapping
\begin{align}
z_1\mapsto iz_1=w_1\\
z_2\mapsto iz_2=w_2\\
z_3\mapsto z_3=w_3\\
z_4\mapsto z_4=w_4
\end{align}
This is a complex linear transformation, thus holomorphic. We see that
\begin{align}
\varphi^*f=-1-z_1^2-z_2^2+z_3^2+z_4^2=-g
\end{align}
It follows that $Z(f)$ and $Z(g)$ are biholomorphic.
